# Spacing between service panel and RV sub panel (both on same outdoor freestanding plywood/post)

Tags: electrical-panel

What is the distance requirements or recommendations for spacing between the 100 amp service panel with meter to the 100 amp Rv sub panel? These will be mounted on marine plywood supported by 4x4 or 6x6 posts and the plywood will be 2ft x 4ft wide, at about 68" high
There will be 2" conduit between them, just curious how far about to space them. Min/Max?
Thanks
Dean

Answer (score 0):

The panel can be mounted directly below there is not a minimum height or spacing for the service panel. There are maximums  6’7”  for the max height of the disconnect. You could have the panel touching the ground (not a good idea).
The only exception to this is if close to a body of water that floods then the panel has to be 24” above the normal high water.

Note I have worked in local areas that have had 18/24” minimum heights for the bottom of service panels outside but this is not in the NEC.
It is best to check but the standard code a minimum is not listed
The 2 boxes could be connected with feed thru bushings or nipples to whatever you want no money max on the separation either.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The panels will be mounted side by side, not one above the other. They will be connected with 2" conduit / Locknuts  & Insulating nuts on each end. And I will add a clamp in between just for good measure.

Comment: You will need insulating bushings not clamps on the inside of each panel if use you use nipples. Same thing side by side though, the maximum height of the highest point of any breaker in the panel is 6’7” they can be as close or far as nipple of whatever length you choose. Make sure to use sealing lock nits or Myers hubs on exterior surfaces or that may get flagged as not rain tight (one thing my inspectors look for)

Comment: Here is what I planned to use to connect the two panels. 2" pvc conduit, PVC Male Terminal adapter, 2" rigid sealer conduit locknut and 2" rigid plastic insulating bushing.     My understanding that is is an acceptable installation. And from bottom of service panel I am doing the same setup, just using 3" conduit.

Comment: My understanding is that it is acceptable to use PVC conduit/adapters for connecting metal boxes to each other.

Comment: The clamps are for on the conduit between the two panels to secure it to the board, not inside the panel

Comment: Yes pvc is ok you will need a bond jumper but that is no big deal. I am so used to rigid I forget about other methods, I have seen diy put clamps inside panels thinking they were required. Good job at picking up bushings as they are required #4 wire and larger NEC 300.4 some don’t do it on #4 I have picked up more than a few jobs fixing diy failures in the past.  If the answers or comments are helpful upvotes and check marks accepted answers help others find answers the answers they are looking for.